ESP32 board package takes up a lot of HDD space
I recently installed ESP32 to the arduino IDE and have just discovered it takes up 5.4GB on my HDD!  I know it has to cover a lot of different boards but is there any option to only load in the boards I want - or delete others ?  I just want the ESP Deb Module. My system only has 64GB and Windows takes up a lot of that.
